# Get Offline Installation ID (Windows 8 or similar)

Tags: c#, windows, installation

Is it possible to get the *Windows Offline Installation ID* (*`OfflineInstallationId`* was found in slmgr.vbs)?

This can be achieved on the command-line with:

> slmgr.vbs /dti

This returns the Installation ID without spaces or dashes, is it possible to retrieve this in C#? 
I want to eventually have each block of the ID (there are 9 blocks, 7 numbers in each block) in their own textboxes on a form.

There are 9 blocks, each with 7 numbers

I looked around, but couldn't find any examples for C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible by querying the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)'s `Win32_WindowsProductActivation` (XP and below) or `SoftwareLicensingProduct` (Vista or higher) class:

Requires these namespaces to be declared:

- System
- System.Collections.Generic
- System.Management
- System.Text

Declare those namespaces at the *top* of your codefile with `using`, as per se:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
```

then use the following code in a function:

```
ManagementScope Scope;
Scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
Scope.Connect();
ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT OfflineInstallationId FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct");
ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
{
    //Do whatever with the Offline Installation ID here.   
}
```

I noticed that because I used Windows 8.1's 'refresh' feature once, my WMI returned *two* Offline Installation IDs for me, therefore this should be something you need to consider (*the first Offline Installation ID is the **valid one***):

[image]

You may want something similar to this:

```
static string getOfflineInstallId()
{
    ManagementScope Scope;
    Scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
    Scope.Connect();
    ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT OfflineInstallationId FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct");
    ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

    foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
    {
        if (WmiObject["OfflineInstallationId"] != null)
            return WmiObject["OfflineInstallationId"].ToString();
    }
    return ""; //Making the compiler happy.
}
```

As mentioned earlier, `SoftwareLicensingProduct` with `OfflineInstallationId` only works on Windows versions newer than Vista (e.g, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, and 10), therefore if you (or the users of your program) wish to use it on XP or earlier, you *may* be able to use the following, but however as I do not have access to XP I am unable to test this:

```
ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT GetInstallationID FROM Win32_WindowsProductActivation");
```

If you want to separate each block of the ID and insert into a `TextBox` into a Windows Form (WinForm), you can use the below code:

```
string installId = getOfflineInstallId();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool fRun = false;
for (int i = 0; i < installId.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 7 == 0)
    {
        if (fRun)
            sb.Append('-');
        else
            fRun = true; //Stops a '-' being added at the 1st position.
    }
    sb.Append(installId[i]);
}
idTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Something like this:

[image]

Further to this, you'll also need to reference the System.Management libraries by right-clicking on **References** in Solution Explorer, clicking on `Add New Reference`, and adding `System.Management` and `System.Management.Instrumentation` to the project:

[image]

The project used in this example can be downloaded [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!XkYGEDQQ!6V9M9Rf0TaK061u_CSiRjQQSQ_quuGUDR_o0o4MJPy4) (*requires Visual Studio 2013 or higher*).

Comment: Thank you for the code, but I stand on the tube.
Is it possible that you can make the the code a little easier for me, please?
I would like this as a Windows Forms :-)

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I stand a little on the tube. I added the code in WinForms but with error. Do you have maybe the project file that I can see what was wrong? I'm absolutely beginner, I can write only simple stuff in C# but this one is to high for me :-( Thank you and sorry for that but you have a nice solution for WinForms :-)

Comment: @user2422690 What do you mean 'on the tube'? What is the error exactly?. See my edit.

Comment: I meant "on the tube" should be an adage (from a website with adages (German -> English), I don't really understand where to add the code :-( I used the References in Solution Explorer, the items are selected and active. I get following error: "ManagementScope' is a namespace but is used like a type".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81195/discussion-between-cybermonkey-and-user2422690).

Comment: See my edit. I feel as if you need to consult some good programming books before you continue with your project. Your other questions also have the same result; you get an answer but don't realise what the code does, although it does *what you asked*. You should really have an understanding of the question's subject before asking it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to read some books and code, but I wrote so far simple programs.

Comment: @user2422690 Please accept my answer by clicking the green tick next to the voting buttons. You can directly execute the `slmgr.vbs /ipk` command, adding the `MultipleActivationKey` to the `string` object, providing you already have the `MultipleActivationKey`. Ask a new question for this, and I'll answer it.

Comment: OK, Currently I can't create a new question on stackoverflow, message: "You have reached your question limit". I would be happy if I can ask you again :-) Thanks again

Comment: @user2422690 You're currently question-banned since you've asked too many low-quality questions (the system automatically does this). Edit some of your questions (***don't** add fluff!*), and perhaps users will upvote your questions and thus left you out of the question ban.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, I must look. Is it possible to change the ID? I found WMI Manager and I see the ID under Class Details -> Instances :-) A buddy has a problem with his ID and he can't activate his Windows 8.1 again by phone. He needs a new ID to activate again without new installation.

Comment: @user2422690 No, it's not possible to change the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, you should also check the Name Or ApplicationID.
If you installed office, you will get two or more OfflineInstallationIds.

Check the Name contains `Windows` or check the ApplicationID equals `55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f`

PS: I dont know if the AppliactionID changes between diffrent version of Windows. I did some Google search and found it seems a static value.

Comment: It appears to be static. I’ve tested with Windows 10, Server 2008 R2, Server 2012 R2, and Server 2016. So it’s probably been static since at least the 7 days.